# How to specify SameSite value for javax.servlet.http.Cookie

Tags: java, cookies, servlets

Having for example:

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;

// some code ....


        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
        
        cookie.setMaxAge(someValue);
```

How do I set [SameSite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) value for it ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Servlet 6.0+

It's only possible since Servlet API version 6.0 (part of Jakarta EE 10) which introduced a new [`Cookie#setAttribute()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/http/cookie#setAttribute(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) method.

```java
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, value);
cookie.setMaxAge(maxAge);
cookie.setAttribute("SameSite", "None");
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Note that there's no [`Cookie#setSameSite()`](https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/issues/175) method for the very simple reason that [the proposal for the `SameSite` attribute](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-02), which was posted at 7 August 2017, is to the day of today [**still**](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-12) not part of the official HTTP cookie spec. This was also the reason why it took so long before it was possible to manipulate the `SameSite` attribute via the Servlet API. The Servlet API guys basically waited for it to end up in the official spec. But in the end it didn't seem to make it into the final spec as quick as expected but yet Google Chrome is already using it to full extent without backwards compatibility. So ultimately a more generic method was introduced and the rest of Cookie API was slightly adjusted ([initiated by yours truly](https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/pull/399)).

### Servlet 5.0-

If you can't upgrade your servletcontainer to a version implementing a minimum of Servlet API version 6.0 (e.g. Tomcat 10.1+, Jetty 12+, WildFly 27+, GlassFish 7+, etc), then you'll have to create the cookie as a plain vanilla `String` [following the syntax of the `Set-Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#syntax) and add it to the response using [`HttpServletResponse#addHeader()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/6.0/apidocs/jakarta.servlet/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletresponse#addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)).

```java
String cookie = name + "=" + value + "; Max-Age=" + maxAge + "; SameSite=None";
response.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie);
```

### JSESSIONID cookie

If you actually wanted to manipulate the `SameSite` attribute of the servletcontainer's built-in `JSESSIONID` cookie, then you have to adjust the configuration of the server itself and/or the proxy in front of it. Consult its documentation for detail.

In case of for example Tomcat 8.5.48+/9.0.28+ you can [configure](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/cookie-processor.html#Standard_Implementation) it from the webapp on via `META-INF/context.xml` as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
   <CookieProcessor sameSiteCookies="none" />
</Context>
```

And in case of Jetty 9.4.23+ you can configure it from the webapp on via `WEB-INF/web.xml` with one of `__SAME_SITE_*__` constants defined in [`org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpCookie`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http/10.0.0.beta0/org.eclipse.jetty.http/org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpCookie.html#field.summary) as a cookie config **comment** as follows:

```xml
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <comment>__SAME_SITE_NONE__</comment>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for jetty I need jetty 10+ ?

Comment: I am going to accept to answer anyway, but I still have a doubt not strictly related to this, if you want to answer but it's anyway ok: my config is the classic web app behind a reverse proxy (nginx), where I have the `location` defined for my app and the `proxy_pass`. Can I solve this problem at nginx / localtion level ?

Comment: I can't answer that off top of head so here's a link: https://serverfault.com/q/849888